# trying to test zero length output from command in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I'm sort of a newbie when it comes to shell scripting. What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to grep a running log file and take action if the grep returns data.

```
# grep for "success" in the log which will tell us if we were successful
tail -f file.log | grep success > named_pipe &

# send signal to my server to do something
/bin/kill -10 $PID

timeout=0;
while : ; do
    OUTPUT=$(cat < named_pipe)
    if test [-n] $OUTPUT
        then
            echo "output is '" $OUTPUT "'"
            echo_success
        break;
    else
        timeout=$((timeout+1))
        sleep 1 
        if [ $timeout -ge $SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT ]; then
            echo_failure
            break
        fi
    fi
done
```

I'm finding that even when "success" is not in the log, test [-n] $OUTPUT returns true. This is because apparently OUTPUT is equal to " ". Why is OUTPUT a single space rather than empty?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a smaller test case for your problem:

```
output=""
if test [-n] $output
then
  echo "Why does this happen?"
fi
```

This happens because when `$output` is empty or whitespace, it expands to nothing, and you just run `test [-n]`.

`test foo` is true when `foo` is non-empty. It doesn't matter that your `foo` is a flag wrapped in square brackets.

The correct way to do this is without the brackets, and with quotes:

```
if test -n "$output"
then
  ...
fi
```

As for why `$OUTPUT` is a single space, that's simple: it isn't. `echo` just writes out its arguments separated as spaces, and you specified multiple arguments. The correct code is `echo "output is '$OUTPUT'"`

Comment: Thank you. Obviously, I have many problems with this script. Unfortunately, even with your improvements, I am apparently still not successfully writing to and reading from this pipe. I can open another terminal and successfully do "tail -f file.log | grep success" while this is running. But in my script, 'if test -n "$OUTPUT"' never returns true.

Comment: Oh, I just realized there's a "mkfifo named_pipe" I believe I should be calling...

Comment: I realized I had an additional problem here. Basically, the named_pipe was never being flushed because so little data was being inserted into it. So, I decided to change things to tail the entire log file and pipe that, then grep "success" from that pipe. I also had better luck piping into a temporary file than using a named pipe for some reason.